# VB.NET: How to handle variable type (parameter & return value)?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to replace these two functions

```
Function f1 (s As String) As class1()
  Dim a() As String = Split(s)
  Dim b(UBound(a)) As class1
  For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(a)
    b(i) = New class1(a(i))
  Next
  f1 = b
End Function
```

and

```
Function f2 (s As String) As class2()
  Dim a() As String = Split(s)
  Dim b(UBound(a)) As class2
  For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(a)
    b(i) = New class2(a(i))
  Next
  f2 = b
End Function
```

with a generic function something like

```
Function fGeneric (s As String,T As Type) As T()
  Dim a() As String = Split(s)
  Dim b(UBound(a)) As T
  For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(a)
    b(i) = New T(a(i))
  Next
  fGeneric = b
End Function
```

?

**SOLUTION**

```
Class class1
  Private _Name As String
  Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Get
      Name = _Name
    End Get
  End Property
  Sub New(s As String)
    _Name = s
  End Sub
End Class

Function fGeneric(Of T) (s As String) As IEnumerable(Of T)
  Dim a() As String = Split(s)
  Dim b(UBound(a)) As T
  For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(a)
    b(i) = GetType(T).InvokeMember( _
      Nothing, _
      BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or _
      BindingFlags.Public Or _
      BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
      BindingFlags.Instance Or _
      BindingFlags.CreateInstance, _
      Nothing, _
      Nothing, _
      New Object(){a(i)} _
    )
  Next
  fGeneric = b
End Function
```

`Response.Write(fGeneric(Of class1)("a b c")(1).Name)` outputs `b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function fGeneric(Of T) (ByVal s As String, ByVal createT As Func(Of String, T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
  Return Split(s).Select(Function(a) createT(a))
End Function
```

call it like this

```
fGeneric(Of class1)("some, string, value", Function(a) Return New class1(a))
```

Comment: I get `Type 'Func' is not defined.` on the first line.

Comment: @ic3b3rg You need at least .Net 3.5 for this.  `Func` is in the System namespace otherwise.

Comment: I changed the Application's Pool to `ASP.NET v4.0` and also tried changing the server .NET version to 4.0.30319 but I'm having problems... first was a no write access error on `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` which didn't exist... I created and added the permission but now I get `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0 ...`.  It seems like I'm missing something - ideas?

Comment: OK, I had to install .NET 4... now I get `Expression expected` when calling fGeneric

Answer (score 2):

As @Joel points out this can be elegantly solved with linq, but to keep close to @ic3b3rg's question, the syntax would be:

```
Function fGeneric(Of T As New) (s As String, createT As Func(Of String, T)) As T()
  Dim a() As String = Split(s)
  Dim b(UBound(a)) As T
  For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(a)
    b(i) = createT(a(i))
  Next
  fGeneric = b
End Function

fGeneric(Of class1)("some, string, value", Function(a) Return New class1(a))
```

**Edit**

Taking a closer look I don't think that this will work, since we have never said that a `T` can be constructed out of a `String`. We've only said that `T` can be created with `new`. I don't know how to solve it... any suggestions are welcome (feel free to edit).

Comment: I get `Arguments cannot be passed to a 'New' used on a type parameter.` on `b(i) = New T(a(i))`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Reflections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx).  I think it can help you get a result more closely relating to your example.