# Constructor requirements on generics parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129232/vb-net-how-to-handle-variable-type-parameter-return-value/6129353#6129353) question I started thinking about how to handle constructor requirements in C#.

Assume that I have:

```
T SomeMethod<T>(string s) : where T : MyInterface
{
    return new T(s);
}
```

I want to set the requirement on `T` that it can be constructed out of a string, but as far as I know, constructor definitions are not allowed as part of interfaces. Is there a standard way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an init method or a property to your interface,

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void Init(string s);
    string S { get; set; }
}

T SomeMethod<T>(string s) : where T : MyInterface, new()
{
    var t = new T();
    t.Init(s);

    var t = new T
    { 
        S = s
    };

    return t;
}
```

As you can't specify arguments to constructor constraints

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to dynamically invoke the constructor:

```
// Incomplete code: requires some error handling
T SomeMethod<T>(string s) : where T : MyInterface
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), s);
}
```

The problem with that is that you lose type safety: if you try to use this with a MyInterface implementation that does not have a matching constructor, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it required to have a constructor that takes a string input, you need to implement an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
     public BaseClass<T>(string input)
     {
         DoSomething(input);
     }

     protected abstract void DoSomething(string input);
}
```

Your derived class then simply provides implementation for the abstract method and it can then pick up any interfaces it wants.

```
public class Sample<T> : BaseClass<T>, IMyInterface
{
    public Sample<T>(string input)
       : base(input)
    {
    }

    protected override void DoSomething(string input)
    {
    }

    public void MyInterfaceMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use the abstract base class in `where T : BaseClass<T>`?

Comment: This does not force anything.  Derived classes may provide parameterless constructors and simply pass a constant string to the base class constructor, for eacample.